# How can I align a div at the edge of a div above it when said div is using automatic positioning?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>`:

```
<div id="placeHolder" class="card"><h1> A title!</h1><p>Some text!</p> </div>
```

and a second `<div>` containing some text and a `<form>`:

```
  <div id="inputFields"><h4 class="header middle">edit</h4>
      <div id="inputs"> 
          <form id="form-inputs"><br>
              Label <input class="input" type="text"> Label <input class="input" type="text"><br>
              Label <input class="input" type="text"> Label <input class="input" type="text"><br>
              Label <input class="input" type="text"> Label <input class="input" type="text"><br>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I am using CSS to automagically center the first div right where I want it on the page:

```
.card {
width: 850px;
height: 350px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 150px;
left: auto;
top: auto; 
background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

This is great because the `<div>` does a reasonably well job of keeping itself centered. However I now want to align the second `<div>` with the first one so that it is directly under it along the left edge.

That's what I can't figure out how to do. I tried setting the second `<div>` to:

```
#inputFields {
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
}
```

But that doesn't work. I'm not sure why, but I'm guess it is because I haven't set the height and width manually.

How can I align these two `<div>`s next to each other?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sethj/hrj25/8/embedded/result/) of what it looks like currently. Basically I want to position the second `<div>` under the first one along it's left edge.

Comment: `left: auto` and `top: auto` are the default values, so don't expect them to do magical things. Moreover, `left` and `top  have no effect in statically positioned elements.

Comment: @Oriol Ah. I didn't know that (although I kinda guessed). That clears a few things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the same width to the second div and also give it auto margins like so:

```
#inputFields {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 850px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LHkhG/embedded/result/